# Android getText from dynamically created adapter list view

Tags: android, textview, gettext

I got a custom adapter list view. Its layout like as follows

```
RelativeLayout
   LinearLayout
       TextView
       Button
```

Need to add a click event on that Button. In that event needs to take the text from that TextView and pass it to the next Activity.

I got the following code

```
holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View vp) {

        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)vp.getParent();
        TextView tv = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.name);
        String text = tv.getText().toString();

    }
});
```

But it is crashing on `String text = tv.getText().toString();`

Any idea ?

**Update**

```
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659): Process: com.atc.detectoract, PID: 16659
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at com.atc.detectoract.CustomAdapter$2.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:129)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 19:59:12.877: E/AndroidRuntime(16659):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: Add the catlog (I assume an NPE on "tv") and also the layout XML, don't just explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
But it is crashing on String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

You have a `NullPointerException`. `tv` is null

You can use `setTag` and `getTag`.

```
holder.btn.setTag(holder.tv.getText().toString()); // set tag
```

Then

```
holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View vp) {

        String value = (String)vp.getTag(); // get tag

    }
});
```